# Independent action in loop iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7, uitextview

There is some action that is executed in a loop, a certain number of iterations. In every iteration is formed string to be displayed in the `UITextView`.

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {

sTest *sT = new sTest();
int res;

for (int i=0; i<300; i++)
{
   res = sT->test_fun(N1[i], M1[i], 10000);              
   [_textView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@res=%d\n", _textView.text, res]];
}
```

With this approach, UI waits until cycle ends, and displays all the lines at once in textview. And I would like that each row displays in each iteration.

Using `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(StringLoop) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` has no effect.

Tell me how to do it. Example is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, you don't appear to understand the event-based environment you are operating in.  You can do what you want using either a timer (`NSTimer`), a background thread or *grand central dispatch*.

Comment: i'm newbie in ios development, and i need an example to understand how to update textview in UI-thread from background thread or etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that what you want is what you should be doing, but the most common implementation for concepts like you describe would be to run your loop on a background thread, and then make calls to the main thread to update the UI when needed. I've included one of the most "readable" and understandable implementations below, but as mentioned in comments, the Grand Central Dispatch is well-suited to your needs.

```
-(void)startItAll
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuffInBackground) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)doStuffInBackground
{
    //do math
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doStuffInMain) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

-(void)doStuffInMain
{
    //update necessary UI
}
```

Comment: Then you should mark it as an accepted answer and code it into your project and become rich and famous!